# How to reload MVC view using AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have ASP.NET application. The code looks as following:

View (List.html):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Events</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="t in ticketGroups">
            <td>{{t.Artist}}</td>
            <td>{{t.ActionDate}}</td>
            <td>{{t.Price}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="t.NewPrice" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<section>
    <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()">Ok</a>
</section>
```

AngularJS:

```
'use strict';

//Routing
var ChangePriceApp = angular.module('ChangePriceApp', ['ngRoute', 'ConcertServices'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/list', { templateUrl: 'partials/ChangePrice/List.html', controller: "ListController" })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list' });
    }]);

ChangePriceApp.controller("ListController", ["$scope", "ChangePrice", function ($scope, ChangePrice) {

    ChangePrice.get().success(function (ticketGroups) {
        $scope.ticketGroups = ticketGroups;
    });

    $scope.save = function () {
        ChangePrice.save($scope.ticketGroups).success(function () {
            ChangePrice.get().success(function (ticketGroups) {
                $scope.ticketGroups = ticketGroups;
            });
            toastr.success("saved");
        });
    }
}]);
```

Initially, the view displays data correctly. I change data and click "Ok" to save it. The issue is after I clicked "Ok", all data disappeared. I want to reload the view with updated data.

UPDATE:

The MVC methods:

```
public class PriceController : ConcertApiController
{
    private readonly ITicketModelService _service;

    public PriceController(ITicketModelService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<RevaluationTicketGroup> GetRevaluationList()
    {
        return _service.GetRevaluationList(CurrentUser);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void PostRevaluationList(IEnumerable<RevaluationTicketGroup> tickets)
    {
        _service.PostRevaluationList(CurrentUser, tickets);
    }
}
```

The AngularJS service:

```
.factory('ChangePrice', function ($http, ErrorUI) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $http.get('/RestApi/api/Price/').error(ErrorUI.showApiError);
        },
        save: function (ticketGroups) {
            return $http.post('/RestApi/api/Price/', ticketGroups).error(ErrorUI.showApiError);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What do `ChangePrice.get()` and `ChangePrice.save()` return?

Comment: ChangePrice.get() returns the list and populate the table, and ChangePrice.save() saves the changes. The methods behind worked out correctly, but the view wasn't refreshed.

Comment: But they return $http promises right? Could we see those methods please? Might not be important but won't hurt

Comment: Please, take a look at "UPDATE" section above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the problem is but I re-factored your promise chain in a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/M2xS3J6MqujomcJ0qxYr?p=preview) to something like below and it seemed to update correctly. Try this;

**factory**

```
get: function(){
  return $http
    .get('/RestApi/api/Price/')
    .then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(ErrorUI.showApiError);
},

save: function (ticketGroups) {
    return $http
        .post('/RestApi/api/Price/', ticketGroups)
        .catch(ErrorUI.showApiError);
}
```

**controller**

```
 ChangePrice
      .get()
      .then(function (ticketGroups) {
          $scope.ticketGroups = ticketGroups;
      });

 $scope.save = function () {

    ChangePrice
      .save($scope.ticketGroups)
      .then(function(){
          toastr.success("saved");
          return ChangePrice.get()
      })
      .then(function(ticketGroups){
          $scope.ticketGroups = ticketGroups;
      });

 }
```

Comment: I can't even get the initial data now.

Comment: In the `ChangePrice.get().then()` callback what do you get when you `console.log(response)`. Could you make a plunker demo with some dummy data, it would be much easier to see what's what.

Comment: Something's wrong with the syntax that you used. I'd like to stay with "success" style instead of "get".

Comment: Try removing the `error()` method chained to your `$http.post()` call that's inside your `save()` method. I don't think it's returning the promise so that might be causing the issue. Apart from that I'm not sure how to help without seeing what your seeing in a demo.